# Handling custom logger across different modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

Creating a custom logger for my purpose using python which can be used across different modules just by importing and calling a custom_log method.

This is MyLogger.py script.

```
import datetime
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import colorlog
from pathlib import Path

class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, verbose=1):
        log_dir_path = Path("../logs")
        file_name_format = '{year:04d}{month:02d}{day:02d}-{hour:02d}{minute:02d}{second:02d}.log'
        file_msg_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
        console_msg_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s'

        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        if (verbose == 1):
            max_bytes = 1024 ** 2
            backup_count = 100
            t = datetime.datetime.now()
            file_name = file_name_format.format(year=t.year, month=t.month, day=t.day, hour=t.hour, minute=t.minute,
                                                second=t.second)
            file_name = os.path.join(log_dir_path, file_name)
            file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=file_name, maxBytes=max_bytes, backupCount=backup_count)
            file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            file_formatter = logging.Formatter(file_msg_format)
            file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
            logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        if (verbose == 1):
            cformat = '%(log_color)s' + console_msg_format
            colors = {'DEBUG': 'green', 'INFO': 'cyan', 'WARNING': 'bold_yellow', 'ERROR': 'bold_red',
                      'CRITICAL': 'bold_purple'}
            date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            formatter = colorlog.ColoredFormatter(cformat, date_format, log_colors=colors)
            stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    def custom_log(self, level, msg):
        logging.log(getattr(logging,level),msg)
```

I have 2 other scripts within the same directory as below, just need to initialize MyLogger() in Test1.py at beginning of the test and expecting to use custom_log in all other scripts. Missing something here to make this work,either in the way of initializing or the way of importing. Any support how to get this done.

Test1.py

```
from MyLogger import MyLogger

class StartTest():
    def __init__(self):
        MyLogger.custom_log('DEBUG','Debug messages are only sent to the logfile.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyLogger()
    StartTest()
```

Test2.py

```
from MyLogger import MyLogger

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        MyLogger.custom_log('DEBUG','Debug messages are only sent to the logfile.')

    def TestMethod(self):
        MyLogger.custom_log('INFO','Debug messages are only sent to the logfile.')
```

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by creating a logger with a specific name instead of using root logger. `logging.log()` uses always the root logger. So, you can define a logger with a specific name instead of creating a new Logging channel.

An example which is inline with your need

```
class MyLogger:
    logger: logging.Logger = None

    @staticmethod
    def configure(verbose=1):
        log_dir_path = Path("../logs")
        file_name_format = '{year:04d}{month:02d}{day:02d}-{hour:02d}{minute:02d}{second:02d}.log'
        file_msg_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
        console_msg_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s'

        logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        cformat = '%(log_color)s' + console_msg_format
        colors = {'DEBUG': 'green', 'INFO': 'cyan', 'WARNING': 'bold_yellow', 'ERROR': 'bold_red',
                  'CRITICAL': 'bold_purple'}
        date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        formatter = colorlog.ColoredFormatter(cformat, date_format, log_colors=colors)
        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        MyLogger.logger = logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyLogger.configure()
    MyLogger.logger.error("debug message")
```

Once the `MyLogger.configure` is called, then you can use the `MyLogger.logger.*` any where in your app / scripts.

This can be done without a helper class as well. Create a logger configuration file. Configure your custom logger with a different name rather than root, and from your code always call `logging.getLogger("name-of-logger")` to create a logging instance.